# How to get entities from multiple tables with one LINQ call?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-core

I've 4 tables and 4 calls to DB to get information from each of them. Trying to make it more optimal and get all 4 entities in 1 call.
This is my current code

```
var teacher = await Teachers
    .Where(t => t.Id == teacherId)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

var student = await Students
    .Where(s => s.Teacher == teacher)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);

var studentGrade = await StudentGrades
    .Where(s => s.StudentId == student.Id)
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

var studentPlace = await StudentPlaces.
    .Where(sp => sp.Id == student.StudentPlaceId)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Is there a way to get all 4 of these entities under one call?

Student table has 1-to-1 relationship with Teacher.
I tried to do joins but it looks ugly. I have way too many nested objects.

```
var result= await Students.
           .Join(Teachers, u => u.Teacher, e=>e, (student, teacher) => new { student, employee })
           .Join(StudentGrades, u=>u.student.Id, up=>up.StudentId, (student, studentGrade) => new { student, studentGrade})
           .Join(StudentPlaces, up=>up.student.student.Id, upr=>upr.Id, (student, studentPlace) => new { student, studentPlace})
           .Where(x => x.student.student.teacher.Id == teacherId)
           .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Depends on your Entity Design but you could add those other things as properties to your student and just join them by using .await Students.Include(s => s.Teacher).Include(s => s.Grades)....ToListAsync() giving you all your students, with all the relevant information

Comment: You would need to have the correct foreign key references on the correct entities then you could use ```Include``` as @Sokui said in their comment. You could also use Joins to get all the data you want in a single query.

Info on LINQ Join:https: //www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-joining-operator-join

Comment: You are using Async so you can do in parallel and wait for all to complete.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using this query but You must have physical relations between these tables to the navigation properties. I am assuming that Student has collection of StudentGrades and Student has collection of StudentPlaces for this kind of relation this query is you can use.

```cs
var teacher = await Teachers
    .Include(x => x.Students)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.StudentGrades)
    .Include(x => x.Students)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.StudentPlaces)
    .Where(t => t.Id == teacherId)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Include part is getting related navigation properties which are in relation with Teacher and You have already said that Teacher is linked with Student. ThenInclude is basically used to get the sub-entities for example Student has relation with Grades and StudentPlaces then you can get these by using ThenIclude.

Additional For Linq to Sql

```
    var result = await (from t in Teachers
                 join s in Students
                 on t.Id equals s.TeacherId
                 join g in StudentGrades
                 on s.Id equals g.StudentId
                 join p in StudentPlaces
                 on s.Id equals p.StudentId
                 where t.Id = teacherId
                 select new { t.TeacherName, s.StudentName }).FirstOrDefaultAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Didn't want to change table structures. Added join but I got way too many nested objects. (Updated the question)

Comment: It looks like your table structure needs to be refactor If you use joins in linq to sql then please updated answer.